# What the round is going on?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

This is really annoying me.  All over CBS/ESPN/EVERYWHERE I am hearing that today's NCAA basketball games are round 3 of the tournament.  When did the definition of a round in a tournament change?

I have helped put together literally 100s of baseball, basketball, and soccer tournaments in my life and a round has always been a level in a tournament.  I am sure that 10 years ago that today's games were the 2nd round because it was the 2nd level of the tournament.  Please see a simple google search for [3rd round](https://www.google.com/#q=ncaa+basketball+%22round+3%22&tbm=nws).

So now they are using "round" to mean "day".  Yes it is the 3rd day of the tournament but it is still only the 2nd round.  Why did this change?  Is this the new normal?  Why is this driving me nuts?  When did the meaning of a round in a tournament totally change?

Answer (score 3):

Since 2011 they've added [The First Four](http://basketball.about.com/od/collegebasketballglossary/g/first-four.htm).  The four lowest-seeded teams will play "First Four" games, with the winners advancing as sixteen seeds to play two of the top-seeded teams. The other two first four games will match up the last four teams to receive at-large bids. This is the first round of the tournament according to the [NCAA's official bracket](http://i.turner.ncaa.com/dr/ncaa/ncaa7/release/sites/default/files/external/printable-bracket/2014/bracket-ncaa.pdf).

What should be the first round - 64 teams - the day that all the major games begin is now called the second round by the NCAA.